# Xamarin.iOS DCAppAttestService.AttestKeyAsync(keyId, HashValue) failing with The operation couldn’t be completed. com.apple.devicecheck.error error 2

Tags: xamarin.ios, devicecheck

I am trying to use DCAppAttestService in Xamarin.iOS to attest a key generatd with GenerateKeyAsync() in a real iOS device, but it is failing with this error:

The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.devicecheck.error error 2.)
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'Platform name: 5.')

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetAttestObject(string Challenge)
        {
            DCAppAttestService atserv = DCAppAttestService.SharedService;
            try
            {
                if (atserv.Supported)
                {
                    var keyId = await atserv.GenerateKeyAsync();
                    var Sha256Challenge=Sha256(Challenge);//custom metod to hash.
                    var HashValue = NSData.FromString(Sha256Challenge);
                    var vas = await atserv.AttestKeyAsync(keyId, HashValue); //Error thrown here
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    vas.AsStream().CopyTo(ms);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
                else
                    return null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var S = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }

        }
```

I cannot find any example of using this service in Xamarin.iOS anywhere.

I can generate a device token without problems using:
var tkn = await DCDevice.CurrentDevice.GenerateTokenAsync();

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or show me a sample code to obtain the attest object?

Comment: Hi @RADU, do you have any document or link of implementing DCAppAttestService(App Attestation) in Xamarin iOS other than Apple's document ? I  There is no single document available for Xamarin Forms and Xamarin iOS

Answer (score 1):

Apple's docs indicate that `com.apple.devicecheck.error error 2` is an issue with the input being invalid. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcerror/code/invalidinput

Check your `SHA256()` method. Are you using `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256`, or something else to generate the hash? Is there are reason you're returning a `string` instead of a `byte[]`?

---

I'm not sure this will exactly help you in your specific case, however in my case, it was an issue with the `keyId` having been generated from a previous install of the app (Apple's docs say it should only be generated once per account per app and then stored and then reused, and we were putting it in `Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage` (which equates to the KeyChain on iOS, which can persist between installs due to iCloud) to be retrieved when next required). So `DCAppAttestService` considers the `keyId` to be invalid when the same one is used across app installs.

Because you asked for a sample, here is the core parts of what I'm successfully using (leaving out the check that DCAppAttestService is supported on the device, and handling an exponential backoff when Apple's server is unavailable due to e.g. network conditions)

```cs
using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
    byte[] clientDataHash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(challenge));

    try
    {
        NSData attestation = await _appAttestService.AttestKeyAsync(keyId, NSData.FromArray(clientDataHash));

        return attestation.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
    }
    catch (NSErrorException errEx) when (errEx.Code == (long)DCError.InvalidInput)
    {
        // if keyId was previously stored in SecureStorage/KeyChain before reinstalling, it might now be invalid
        // we can remove the value and regenerate it and attestation should suceed
        SecureStorage.Remove("AppAttestKeyId");
        
        // try retrieving the challenge again
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sebbs128, do you have any document or link of implementing DCAppAttestService(App Attestation) in Xamarin iOS other than Apple's document ? I  There is no single document available for Xamarin Forms and Xamarin iOS

Comment: I don't sorry @Jamal. I mostly figured it out from [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity) and discovering the equivalent .NET method shapes with Intellisense. The result looks a lot like Apple's examples (language differences aside), and the important part of it is the example in my answer.